# solved - Decreasing lagging on router, while gaming

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lag

Solution: #1 answer, #3 comment

I had absolutely no idea where to post this question and get a professional answer for it but here goes...

Okay, so I guess everyone whos is reading this had played online, and so I was playing LoL again tonight and my brother decided that now was a great time to go on youtube and start watching a movie, so my ping (connecting from South Africa to EU west server) is around 190-220 average, however it started spiking to 2000 and average was 600-800, so it arised the question, how ther hell can I "kick" him off for the time being

I tried reasoning it out with him but its like playing chess with a pigeon, he's studying to be an engineer, and I just cant win an argument with him, so i need to step it up a level...

I have in the past used the aireplay method by sending deauth packets but it only helped so much, is there another way of either kicking a peer of the local wifi or decreasing the lag spikes while in session or even splitting the bandwidth equally in 2 or 3,etc

What do I do

p.s. sorry if off topic, if it is not appropriate, just say which website will be able to help or assist me...

Comment: Who controls the router and Internet connection, what kind of Internet connection do you have and what router ?  The appropriate way to modify connection settings is on the router.   There is also the question of "do you have the right to take priority over your brother ?"  Sending "death packets" does not seem like you have the authority to do what you are wanting and is, to me anyway, abhorent - if you are not in a position to legitimately control the connection, pay for your own !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that might help is to look in your router admin settings for a Quality of Service (QoS) setting. This will enable you to 'reserve' minimum bandwith on a specific port or to a specific IP adress in your home network.

Here's the description of my own router's QoS settings:

> Quality of Service (QoS) refers to the capability of a network to provide better service to selected network traffic. The primary goal of QoS is to provide priority including dedicated bandwidth, controlled jitter and latency (required by some real-time and interactive traffic), and improved loss characteristics. Also important is making sure that providing priority for one or more flows does not make other flows fail.

Comment: thnx I just did that and I will see if it works, lol my brother is online again so ill see if my ping is high...

Comment: And did it work? Also make sure you have forwarded the right ports for your game to your computer. This can also remove lag and increase connectivity

Comment: yes, it did, my bro is online watching a movie, and I am playing with +10 than usaul ping, I went to QoS settings in router config, put port for lol 5000-5500 UDP as highest priority and now it works like a charm, THANK YOU EVERYONE