# How to decrease lagging in gaming? Does buying new router helps?

Tags: networking, router, gaming

How to decrease lagging in gaming? Does buying new router helps?

I want to play games, and download games in the meanwhile. I don't understand how can game lag if it only uses for example 5% of my maximum bandwidth, and I limit my other downloads to for example 50% or less. There is still 45% or more bandwidth left, so why is there a lagg? Is my router cheap, if yes when buying what type of router should i buy?

P.S. I already looked in the QoS settings like suggested in this post
[solved - Decreasing lagging on router, while gaming](https://superuser.com/questions/668510/solved-decreasing-lagging-on-router-while-gaming)

Comment: What is the latency at the time you experience lag?

Comment: Are you limiting your uploading as well as your downloading? Latency in games is more often caused by not having enough upload available.

Comment: I would look into getting a internet plan with higher speeds. What is your current plan? I know comcast offers 100+mb/s download speeds. Obviously these numbers are not guaranteed but if you're paying for a slower plan that might be your issue. Speedtest.net can tell you your download/upload speeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By direct connection I think he means as opposed to wireless.  You can hook the router directly with a cable to your pc and it's a lot faster.  When I was taking online classes, downloading a class video wirelessly took over an hour but downloading a class when I was directly connected took a couple of minutes.

The other thing I did to speed up my internet (I don't do gaming), was I replaced my old router with a new one.  The guy at the store that sells routers would have one he would recommend for your situation, if that's the problem.  My old router was slowing my internet speeds from 15 to 3.  When I got the new router my speeds are back up now, even for my cell phone on wifi (which is 10 now and was 1 before).

Answer (score 2):

If the router is at fault yes, buying another router with better support might help. Now if your problem is geographical, your ISP, your system or some other intern/extern variable, then is little what the new router could do and you will be suffering of lag even with the new router.

Comment: And how about network card, is having on board network card bad for gaming?

Comment: @Davidenko it looks that you have no idea from where comes your lag. You must first check your system requirements, then for networking issues. It's a tedious process but if you are able to identify the bottlenecks and fix them, yeah, your lag will go away.

Comment: What sort of port do you have 10/100 or 10/100/1000 because that would be the only thing that could make a different.  If you compare a 10/100/1000 network to another 10/100/1000 network card and one is more expensive ( or better quality ) they both will perform basically the same.

Comment: @Davidenko you may check for network latency using something like [this](http://superuser.com/q/713690/235569). That will tell you exactly where the lags are.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your ping in this game
2. Test yor bandwidth by speedtest.
3. If router is cheap and your ISP use VPN-like connection ( PPTP/PPPoE or anoter one), instead of direct connection, it can slowed. It happens because this kind of connection use lots of CPU on router. Try to connect computer or laptop directly, without router.

P.S. I talk about lags in online game. And it is no caused by lack of CPU/memory/videocard.

Comment: Ok, tnx I will try with direct connection... How do you mean directly without router? If I use direct connection and not PPPoE I don't need router?

Comment: Your ISP can provide services in a different way. If it is not ADSl or some other modem connection, you most commonly can connect computer directly to cable. Ask ISP`s helpdesk about further instructions, because even if it`s not VPN, you will need some specific settings.

Comment: @Davidenko and you can use VPN connections without router too. Router make it more comfortable (It holds connection, and you dont need setup it on computer) and can provide internet to all of your home gadgets and computers.

Answer (score -3):

I will tell you my story. I went from HORRIBLE LAG/BAD PING/LOW speeds buy upgrading my old all DOCSIS 2 model and sepratre router - to a new DOCIS 3.0 model & router IN ONE! + upgrading Cat5 Cable which is 15 years old, to CAT7 !  With the router+modem in 1x mean means there is no need for a entire 2nd unit/processor which only adds DELAY to process signal from the first - and this has DECREASED my PING from 100MS to just a blazing fast and woppping 15ms!!! THe gameplay has improved soo much its like buying a brand new computer or something... Its insane how smooth the game runs now... And doing this change has has increased my down speeds from 30Mbit to 70Mbit - and upload speed has increased from 1.5Mbit to a freken whopping 5Mbit!!!  So I can say now the lagg probably came form from the upspeed.. 1Mbit compared to 5x that is bigg difference.. plus the new models use multiple threads/connections - to speed up the overall transfer of data (LESS LAGG) added to that I now dont have to pay the rental fee from the cable company for their stupid modem of $5.99 per month - which means my new model/router pays for itself in the first year and is free for the 2nd or 3rd year.

The cable company had me on a 100Mbit plan, but yet they didnt upgrade the 4 year old model they installed 2 years ago..  That modems MAXIUM CAPACITY IS FREKEN 15 Mbit!!!! So I am surpised I was even getting 30 Mbit with it... Now that I upgraded 70Mbit (7.7MBPS download speeds) and uploads of around 4-5Mbit is amazing compared to 1Mbit (1/4) i was getting before.. Also ping dropped from 100-150ms to 5-15ms - which is BEYOND AMAZING!!

Do yourself a BIG FAVOR ,buy a router+model in one (DOCSIS 3) that is approved for your ISP - and watch your speeds double or tripe and your ping reduced by 50-150%

Also make sure you buy CAT-7 cable for that new model/router.. Note that cat5 cables are OLD and not ment for todays world even tho 70% of people still always buy cat5. Buy cat7 cable from your pc/console to the model - cat7 is used for the cabling infrastructure of Gigabit Ethernet. A CAT 7 cable offers performance of up to 600MHz. Put simply, a CAT 7 cable is 10-20x better then cat5.. TRUST ME!

- Cat5: Cat5 supports speeds up to 100Mb/s (100 MHz)
- Cat5e: Cat5e supports speeds up to a Gigabit Ethernet (1,000Mb/s) (100 MHz)
- Cat6: Cat6 supports speeds up to 10 Gigabit Ethernet and can be achieved with distance of 37-55 meters or less depending on the grade of the cable and quality of installation. (1,000Mb/s) (250 MHz)
- Cat6A: Cat6A supports speeds up to 10 Gigabit Ethernet with distance up to 100 meters (10,000 Mb/s)(500 MHz)
- Cat7 & Cat7A: Cat7 & Cat7A support speeds up to 10 Gigabit Ethernet with distance up to 100 meters (10,000 Mb/s)(1000 Mhz)

Examples of when you might use each type of network cable.

- Cat5 - Cat5 cable is out dated. Do not install this.
- Cat5e - Cat5e cable is suitable for Gigabit speeds and networks that change frequently. If the network changes frequently or is temporary in nature, Cat5e may be the optimal selection.
- Cat6 - Cat6 cable is optimal for extra margin and higher performance. Cat6 cable will support gigabit ethernet, but will only support 10 Gigabit Ethernet if the total length and loss is low enough. If a project requires a 10 Gigabit Ethernet connection, Cat6A or higher is recommended.
- Cat6A - Cat6A cable will support speeds up to 10 Gigabit. If a project requires a single installation solution to support the facility and is inteded to stand the test of time, Cat6A will protect the investment and serve as a reliable backbone for the company going into the future.
- Cat7 & Cat7A - Cat7 cable will support 10 Gigabit Ethernet with plenty of margin to spare. Cat7 has pair-sharing capability, making it possible to use one cable to power several different devices at the same time utilizing each pair as needed. For the best and most versatile infrastructure Cat7 provides the solution.

The Cat5 cable was the standard in 1995, Cat5e was standard in 2001 and Cat6 came out in 2002. The Cat6a has been around since 2008. Most businesses still have no need for updating their hardware to Cat7 ethernet cable, much less the Cat7a or Cat8 cables that were first released in 2010 and 2013.

Comment: take a look at [How to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit your answer