# How to check for Networking Latency?

Tags: networking

I'm experiencing network lags. I know this from ping, but I would want to know what hop/node is causing the issue so I can fix it (or at least I know who to blame). How I could I check the latency between hops?

(Any tool should be preferable OS independent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tools for almost any OS that do traceroute or tracepath. The problem with them is interpreting the information correctly and there seems to be a problem in it's usage. For Unix-like and Windows [there's MTR and WinMTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_%28software%29). It does everything that you expect from a traceroute tool.

From unix/linux using:

```
mtr somehost.com
```

Will launch a GUI if available and display hop number, the packet loss percentage (this one is critical), amount of package sent, the last packet time response (similar to ping), an average/median, minimum and maximum response time.

From Windows, just download the zip file, extract it then run it. It will present you a box where you can type the host that you want to test against the interpretation is the same as Unix version.

[image]

Comment: Any packet loss is a bit of a disaster so it should be 0 or just an occasional 1. The kicker for VoIP and games is latency. So the round trip time is key. However, on a tracert, you can expect MOST of the hops to have 100% loss as they wont respond to the ICMP packets for security reasons. The display above indicates some serious network issues!

Comment: @JulianKnight it is an stock photo.

Comment: Whew! I was worried for you! Even a dropped packet to the local router!